# What is the purpose of the *.pro file?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I just started using Qt and noticed that in each example code folder there is a `.pro` file (and there is also a makefile created too... why?). What is the purpose of the `.pro` file?

Comment: Read the answer to your other question, where we already explained this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368534/qt-question-why-does-qt-use-its-own-make-tool-qmake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a multiplatform project file which `qmake` turns into platform-specific makefiles. The main reason for its existence is easier configuration and compilation of multiplatform projects. Compare e.g. to autotools-generated `configure` scripts and makefiles commonly seen in unixland.