# How does boost implements signals and slots?

Tags: c++, boost, signals-slots

To continue another question, lets ask this:

How does Boost implement the signals/slot mechanism?

See:
[How signal and slots are implemented under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406940/how-signal-and-slots-are-implemented-under-the-hood)
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/signals.html

Answer (score 2):

here's an interesting snippet from [this gamedev.net thread](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=456646) to get the discussion rolling

> Original post by Spoonbender So, bonus
>   question: What causes boost::signals
>   to be *that* much slower?
>
> It looks like there are a couple of
>   biggies. First, despite the fact that
>   boost::signals isn't threadsafe, it
>   enters and leaves critical sections a
>   couple of times. Secondly, there's
>   this named-slots thingy which seems to
>   result in overly complex data
>   structures which take a long time to
>   iterate over. And then there's a lot
>   of nickel-and-diming from various
>   housekeeping things it does. Finally,
>   the individual calls have much higher
>   overhead because of boost::bind's
>   runtiminess. It's all functionality
>   that I'm sure someone has a need for,
>   but I don't.