# How does Qt implement signals and slots?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

Can someone explain to me the basic idea of Qt signals&slots mechanism IMPLEMENTATION?
I want to know what all those Q_OBJECT macros do "in plain C++".
This question is NOT about signals&slots usage.

added:
I know that Qt uses moc compiler to transform Qt-C++ in plain C++.
But what does moc do?
I tried to read "moc_filename.cpp" files but I have no idea what can something like this mean

```
void *Widget::qt_metacast(const char *_clname)
{
if (!_clname) return 0;
if (!strcmp(_clname, qt_meta_stringdata_Widget))
    return static_cast<void*>(const_cast< Widget*>(this));
return QDialog::qt_metacast(_clname);
}
```

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406940/how-signal-and-slots-are-implemented-under-the-hood

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Concerning the signals and slots, the `Q_OBJECT` macro adds a virtual function `qt_metacall()` declaration into the class’s declaration which is to be defined later by the the `moc`. (It also adds some declarations for conversion but that’s not too important here.)

The `moc` then reads the header file and when it sees the macro, it generates another `.cpp` file named `moc_headerfilename.cpp` with the definitions to the virtual functions and – you might have asked yourself why you can get away with mentioning the `signals:` in your header file without a proper definition – of the signals.

So, when a signal is called, the definition from the mocfile is executed and `QMetaObject::activate()` is called with the signal’s name and the signal’s arguments.
The `activate()` function then figures out which connections have been established and fetches the names for the appropriate slots.

Then it calls `qt_metacall` with the slot names and the arguments given to the signal and the metacall function delegates this with the help of a large `switch`—`case` statement to the real slots.

As there is no real runtime information possible in C++ concerning the actual names for the signals and slots, as has already been noticed, these will be encoded by the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros to simple `const char*`s (with either "1" or "2" added to the name to distinguish signals from slots).

As is defined in `qobjectdefs.h`:

```
#define SLOT(a)     "1"#a
#define SIGNAL(a)   "2"#a
```

—

The other thing the `Q_OBJECT` macro does is defining the `tr()` functions inside your object which can be used to translate your application.

**Edit**
As you asked what the `qt_metacast` is doing. It checks whether an object belongs to certain class and if it does returns the pointer to it. If it doesn’t, it returns 0.

```
Widget* w = new Widget();
Q_ASSERT(w->qt_metacast("Widget") != 0);
Q_ASSERT(w->qt_metacast("QWidget") != 0);
Q_ASSERT(w->qt_metacast("QObject") != 0);
Q_ASSERT(w->qt_metacast("UnrelatedClass") == 0);
```

This is needed to provide some runtime reflection which is not possible otherwise. The function is called in [`QObject::inherits(const char *)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/latest/qobject.html#inherits) for example and simply checks for inheritance.

Comment: Also check out this blog post for more details: http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html

Answer (score 3):

Those macros do absolutely nothing "in plain C++", - they expand to empty strings (I think).

QT uses a meta-object compiler, that generates C++ code for Q_OBJECT-enabled classes (implementing the signals/slots you define, among other things).

You can read more about it in the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/moc.html#moc).

Comment: Indeed. In fact, if you compile the code, you can look at the produced source.

Comment: Signals and slots need to have a small difference when expanded as you could `connect()` signal to signal and then it wouldn’t be clear what the string stands for.

Answer (score -2):

The basic idea is that you can connect your objects allowing them to execute a method (slot) when a signal is done.

```
connect(pistol,SIGNAL(sigShoot()),runner,SLOT(slotRun()))
```

Doing the connection above, when the pistol emits the signal, the runner will execute its slot.

To do this, you have to declare your signals and slots in your respective classes.

Is the basic idea.

Good luck!

Comment: But the OP was asking about the internal implementation, not how to use it.

Comment: The idea looks like what dojo deals with message system.